# InAppPurchase in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is InAppPurchase available in Windows Phone 7. If it is not available in the Windows Phone 7 SDK, is there any third party library available ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no APIs in the current or upcoming 7.1 (Mango) Windows Phone SDK to provide in-application purchases. You could use any regular payment gateway or web-based service for handling payments, though.